# Différence entre « air conditionné » et « air climatisé » ?

Tags: sens, adjectifs

Y a-t-il une différence de sens ou technique entre « air conditionné » et « air climatisé » ?

Comment: Il me semble que dans l'usage courant en France on ne parle pas d'air conditionné, ou même d'air climatisé, on parle de "climatisation" tout court. De même, l'appareil qui climatise est un "climatiseur", et un endroit équipé d'un climatiseur est "climatisé".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de consensus. Adressons-nous d'abord à un dictionnaire (je prends le *Trésor de la langue française*) :

> [Air conditionné](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conditionn%C3%A9). Air dont la chaleur, l'humidité, la pression sont réglées en fonction de l'atmosphère extérieure ou de l'usage que l'on en fait.
>   [Climatiser](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/climatis%C3%A9). Au moyen d'une circulation d'air traité, maintenir à des conditions déterminées, de température et d'humidité notamment, et régénérer l'air, l'atmosphère d'une enceinte.

La différence n'est pas frappante. Il y a en fait une nuance, mais qui n'est pas universel, sur le but recherché, qui est explicitéee par l'[OQLF](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise) ([GDT](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/gdt.html), article *conditionnement d'air*) : le conditionnement d'air est plutôt industriel alors que la climatisation assure plutôt le confort des humains.

> Le conditionnement d'air est une technique qui concerne davantage les installations ayant pour objet de maintenir des matériaux, des denrées, des appareils, etc., dans des conditions favorables à leur conservation ou à leur fonctionnement, alors que la climatisation a pour objet d'assurer le confort par un ensemble d'opérations créant et maintenant des conditions déterminées de température, d'humidité relative, de vitesse et de pureté de l'air.

La plupart du temps, climatisation implique un refroidissement, par opposition au chauffage. Cette connotation ne se retrouve pas dans *air conditionné*.

Dans certains milieux, le conditionnement est considéré comme plus sophistiqué que la climatisation (qui ne concernerait que la température). Il me semble que c'est particulièrement fréquent chez les vendeurs d'automobiles, comme en témoigne [cet article du magazine canadien *L'Automobile*](http://www.lautomobile.ca/news/air-climatis-ou-air-conditionn/1000185482/) :

> C'est ainsi que l'air d'une voiture sera de plus en plus "conditionné", plutôt que simplement "climatisé", selon Roger Goudreau, le nouveau dg du Comité paritaire de Montréal. On "filtre" déjà l'air, on le "refroidit", on le "gère" de plus en plus avec des contrôles thermostatiques, on en contrôlera éventuellement l'humidité. Des aftermarketers ingénieux nous arriveront sans doute avec des parfumeurs intégrés. Bref, l'air devient "conditionné" plutôt que simplement climatisé, ou refroidi.

Certains voient dans le terme *air conditionné* un anglicisme, *air climatisé* étant le terme français. Cette attitude n'a comme justification que la simple proximité entre le terme *air conditionné* et l'expression anglaise correspondant, *air conditionné* étant tout à fait conforme au génie de la langue et apparu à peu près en même temps. ([1](http://etatslangue.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/l%E2%80%99histoire-loufoque-de-%C2%AB-air-climatise-%C2%BB-et-%C2%AB-air-conditionne-%C2%BB/))

Une autre nuance, plus courante et moins artificielle, consiste déclarer que l'on conditionne l'air (on en change certaines propriétés dans le but de rendre leurs valeurs idéales), mais l'on climatise un espace (on en règle le climat). Ce serait donc un abus de langage que de parler d'*air climatisé* ; l'air est conditionné et le bâtiment climatisé. L'appareil peut s'appeler conditionneur (d'air) ou climatiseur (de bâtiment), c'est selon. ([1](http://etatslangue.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/l%E2%80%99histoire-loufoque-de-%C2%AB-air-climatise-%C2%BB-et-%C2%AB-air-conditionne-%C2%BB/) [2](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/actualites/capsules_hebdo/climatiser_20060727.html) [3](http://www.druide.com/points_de_langue_33.html)) Je rétorque que si impropriété il y a, il s'agit tout au plus d'une métonymie, ce qui est des plus courant dans l'évolution de la langue. On ne saurait donc proscrire l'expression *air climatisé*, qui se justifie de toute façon par l'analyse comme *air passé par un système de climatisation*.

Pour finir, notons qu'il est courant de passer d'une expression à l'autre sans y apporter de nuance. ([1](http://www.legalett.ca/Cooling_fr.htm), [2](http://www.dormirenfrance.fr/climatise-central-s221646.htm) : le titre parle d'« air climatisé », le texte parle d'« air conditionné »).

Comment: j'ai toujours entendu dire effectivement qu'« air conditionné » était un anglicisme, mais votre réponse m'incite à ne pas me braquer … Quoi qu'il en soit, le technicien qui s'en occupe s'appelle un climaticien, ce qui peut apparaître un barbarisme alors que ce n'est qu'un néologisme pas mal formé.

Answer (score 2):

À mon sens, l'air conditionné est de l'air qui circule en circuit fermé sans que l'on puisse régler sa température, *a contrario*, on peut régler la température à des valeurs supérieures ou inférieures à la température de la source (on peut éventuellement jouer sur le degré hygrométrique) de l'air issu d'un système de climatisation.